# node.js /socket.io/Chat return message incorrect?

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I have a problem which is as follows:

If I send a message in English, there is no problem.

But if I send a message in thai language, no message is shown and the message is incorrect eg. input:'ส' program shows: '*'.

I deploy on www.heroku.com
code in github: https://github.com/KraisornRitthiwong/chat
this code:

```
//app.js
var express = require('express'),
app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade'); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('chat', function(data) {
        io.emit('chat', data);
    });
});
```

//index.jade

```
        var socket = io();
        var chatForm = $('#chat-form');
        var chatHistory = $("#chat-history");
        var inputMessage = $('#chat-message');

        inputMessage.focus();

        var username = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

        socket.emit('chat', {
            username: username, 
            message: 'I\'m connected.'
        });


        chatForm.submit(function() {

            alert(inputMessage.val()); 

            socket.emit('chat', {
                username: username, 
                message: inputMessage.val()
            });

            $(this)[0].reset();
            return false;
        });

        socket.on('chat', function(data) {
            alert(data.message);
            if (data.username == username) {
                chatHistory.append($('<li class="message message--me">').text(data.message));
            } else {
                chatHistory.append($('<li class="message">').text(data.username + ': ' + data.message));
            }
            chatHistory[0].scrollTop = chatHistory[0].scrollHeight;

        });
```

thank you very much.